# Binomial Distribution:equivalency between the average and proportion?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, proportion, mean, law-of-large-numbers

Another user and I are having a debate regarding properties of a binomial distribution, most notably the relationship between the proportion and the mean. The central prompt is in quotations:

“I want to find out if the coin-toss algorithm is working as intended. I play 100 games and check how many I go first. I set these as 1's and going 2nd as 0's. I take the sum of the 1's and divide by 100 (an average). Is this a good approximation of the probability of going first that was used in setting up the coin toss algorithm?

Finally, of course you cannot take the average of categorical variables in general (like color of the car, your BMI classification, etc.). However, with regard to determining the probability of an event, taking the average (that is, summing up successes and dividing by total trials) is precisely what Borel's law of large numbers (LLN) is about.”

First, isn’t the above approach calculating the proportion of successes, not the average? Second, in a binomial distribution, is taking the proportion mathematically equivalent to taking an "average" (when observations are represented as 1 or 0)? Third, it was to my understanding that binomial variables are inherently categorical, and thus averaging the 1’s and 0’s are treating an otherwise binomial variable as numerical values. I understand that you can coerce the successes and failures as 1 and 0 accordingly, treat them as numerical values, and perform descriptive statistics (average and variance), but isn’t this just a convoluted way of calculating the proportion of successes?

I explained that taking an average is a measure of central tendency, and that without a known proportion, in a binomial distribution, it wouldn't make sense to perform descriptive statistics besides calculating the proportion of successes. The mean of a binomial distribution is calculated as $X=n p$ where $x$ is the mean, $n$ is the number of trials, and $p$ is the proportion. The proportion and the number of trials do not change, but the average does change leading me to believe that averaging the 1's and 0's does not report the true average of the binomial distribution.

For that matter, is it statistically possible to calculate the average of a binomial data, across multiple independent trials, without a known proportion? Lastly, I am not sure if the law of large numbers (LLN) is being appropriately applied in the above prompt.

Comment: If you are recording 1 for successes and 0 for failures, the proportion of successes *is* the mean.

Comment: I am asking if calculating the mean without a known proportion serves any purpose. The mean, in this context, does not provide any information on the central tendency of the data since the outcomes are dichotomous. At that point, the mean isn't being calculated, rather the proportion. Besides that, I still don't understand what advantages there are in coercing a binomial variable to numeric in binomial statistics.

Comment: Your statements don't make sense. 1. You seem to carry some severe misunderstandings that you should probably ask about first. For example "the mean, in this context" provides direct information about the *population mean*. For example, it is perfectly possible to create a confidence for the population proportion (population mean) from such a sample. [The typical sort of discussion of  measures of "central tendency" popular with many intro books is often extremely misleading and typically would do less harm by omitting it altogether.] ...

Comment: 2. "At that point, the mean isn't being calculated, rather the proportion."  --- this is flat out wrong. I already explained that the mean and the proportion are the same thing in my very first comment. When you code as 0/1 the proportion of 1s *IS THE MEAN*, and this is true for both the sample and the population. Please don't repeat this error again. There's little point in trying to help you if you continue to deny the direct statements of fact we give you.

Comment: 3. You should probably revise your question since it seems to be asking many things that differ from what you say you're asking in comments. Indeed it may be better to rephrase to focus on asking about the premises on which your questions rely. (For example, rather than again state that the proportion isn't the mean, ask about whatever makes you think that it isn't)

Comment: I added more information in the question. What is confusing me is that the formula for calculating the mean of a binomial distribution is μ=np, so how can the average be the same as the proportion when the proportion is used to calculate the average? How can an average change when no values are added or removed and the proportion remains the same?

Comment: You're confusing the mean of the distribution of binomial *count*s with the mean of the distribution of binomial proportions. If $X_i$ is i.i.d. $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$, $i=1,...,n$, then $E(X_i) = p$. If $Y=\sum_i X_i$, then $Y$ is $\text{binomial}(n,p)$ and has expected value $np$. If $Z = \bar{X}$ (the mean of the 0/1 values) then $Z$ is a binomial proportion with expectation $p$. $Y$ is not a mean of $X$'s but a *sum*, and is also not a proportion. $Z$ is both a sample mean and a sample proportion. Its expectation is the population mean of the $X_i$.

Comment: I think that I understand now. I was confused because the 1s and 0s are categorical levels that are converted to numerical, yet they still retain their subjective attributes (1 being success and 0 being failure). Then it seems as though this method only works if 1 is coded as success and 0 as failure. In that case, what advantages would this method provide over performing analyses using success and failures as categorical values? Some analyses of count data require categorical data, which would not be possible if the 1s and 0s are treated as numeric.

Comment: The term "mean" is only meaningful when the values are actual numbers (related to which, see the definition of a random variable). It's a way of making the categorical data into a random variable, and so the proportion in a category becomes the same thing as a mean (among other things), at which point you can do a lot of stuff quite directly (including invoke the LLN ...)

Comment: Your question now seems to boil down to "why use formal random variables to analyze data taking categorical values?" (which would seem to be "so you can use the machinery of random variables")